# Difference between sproutcore and sc-init

Tags: sproutcore

What is the diference between the commands:

`sproutcode gen app AppName`

and

```
sc-init AppName
```

When I'm running the first one I see the following:

```
~ Created directory at apps
WARN 22:36:15.009 ~ For specific help on how to use this generator, type: sc-gen statechart_app --help 
FATAL 22:36:15.009 ~ Permission denied - /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sproutcore-1.9.1/lib/apps
```

If I use the second command `sc-init` it works fine and the application is created in a folder I made.

In order to make `sproutcore` to work I add `sudo` in front of it and the applications I create this way are stored in `/var/libs/gem`.

How can I use the `sproutcore` command without using `sudo` in front of it and also point it to save the application in my desired folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend that you read the [Sproutcore Build Tools Guide](http://guides.sproutcore.com/build_tools.html) to get a good overview of what they offer and each command's purpose.

`sproutcore init` (or `sc-init` for short) is designed to generate a full Sproutcore project with multiple apps inside of it. Whereas `sproutcore gen app AppName` is designed to generate an app in an existing project.

I think your problem with `sproutcore gen` is that you are running it outside of a project, so it's defaulting to the base project directory which happens to be part of the gem, which you do not have access to (well...without using sudo that is).

I bet if you use `sc-init` to create the project, `cd` into the directory, and then run `sproutcore gen app MyAwesomeApp` it will work as you expect.

But definitely check out the guide I linked above as it will walk you through the whole process.